# Can std::error_category be used across dlls?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, dll, stl

I've got a windows dll that throws `std::system_error`s with category `std::system_category()`.

If they get caught inside the dll, no problem I can compare them with a `std::error_condition'`. But, if I catch in my exe that links to the dll, then comparisons always fail because the `std::system_category()` in that context does not == the one in the caught exception.

I'm struggling to understand if this should work and there's a bug, or if this shouldn't be supported?

Both the dll and exe link to the same dll version of the CRT.

Also, if the dll and exe linked to static versions of the CRT, I guess this wouldn't be expected to work?

I read [this description of std::system_category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_category), (emphasis mine):

> Obtains a reference to the **static** error category object for errors
>   reported by the operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Visual C++ 2013.  It is fixed in Visual C++ 2015.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I got the second part of my question wrong, maybe you also know the answer: "f the dll and exe linked to static versions of the CRT, I guess this wouldn't be expected to work?"

Comment: @ScottLangham This won't work at all in Visual C++ 2013 regardless how you link things; the `operator==` will compare the addresses of `error_category` objects in two different modules and return `false`.  In Visual C++ 2015, it _will_ work if both modules link to the Visual C++ libraries DLLs.  If you statically link the Visual C++ 2015 libraries into each module, then this will still happen to work, though it is highly inadvisable to do so,

Comment: @JamesMcNellis How does that work? Usually statically linking a library into different DLLs duplicates all content of said static library. I want the same capability for my own variables.